# Why does this ALTER TABLE query throw syntax error?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error, alter-table

This is the query I'm using:

`ALTER TABLE apartment ADD technical TEXT NOT NULL AFTER is_sale`

Why does it produce a syntax error?

EDIT:

`ALTER TABLE apartment ADD COLUMN technical TEXT NOT NULL AFTER is_sale` still produces an error:

`Error: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE andreevka_apartment ADD COLUMN technincal TEXT NOT NULL AFTER' at line 1`

Also doesn't validate: http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml#parser

Comment: Remember always show whole error in your question.

Comment: u forgot to write `COLUMN` in tour syntax

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It actually turned out that my query was copy-pasted from PhpMyAdmin and had some encoding issues. I pasted it into Notepad++, converted it to ANSI and it worked. Weird.

The syntax was perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have a **syntax error**, to add column you should use `COLUMN` in sentence

```
ALTER TABLE apartment ADD COLUMN technical TEXT NOT NULL
```

EDITED

I think you cannot use `AFTER` with `ALTER` because it won't care of column order, it does not matter for storage or querying.

Comment: Still throws an error, see my edit. Also, why isn't my syntax highlighted? Could it be an encoding problem of some sort?

Comment: @exizt I think this is because of `ALTER` won't care of column order because it does not matter for storage or querying, so just don't use `AFTER` and you are ready to go

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE apartment ADD technical TEXT NOT NULL AFTER is_sale` is working fine and I tested it.I use **HeidiSQL** as client.Here no need of ADD COLUMN.check whether **is_sale** name is correct or **apartment** name is correct

Answer (score -1):

use `ADD COLUMN` for adding new column

```
ALTER TABLE apartment ADD COLUMN technical TEXT NOT NULL AFTER is_sale
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure it's allowed in MySQL, but in Oracle there's another syntax as well:

```
ALTER TABLE apartment ADD (technical TEXT NOT NULL AFTER is_sale);
```